# Skip Crop or Add Custom Footer in antd-img-crop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, crop

Is it possible in anyways to either add a skip option in ImageCrop or add customFooter and add different buttons in there?

```
<ImgCrop
  aspect={1 / 1}
  ref={this.imageCropper}
  shape="rect"
  modalTitle="Crop Artwork"
>
  <Upload
    name="avatar"
    listType="picture-card"
    className="art-uploader"
    showUploadList={false}
    customRequest={this.onArtImageChange.bind(this, item.id)}
    id={"image-" + item.id}
    style={{ width: "250px", height: "250px" }}
  ></Upload>
</ImgCrop>;
```

A modal opens on image select, so I need to add skip option in that, I tried beforeCrop prop but setting it true will simply not open the pop up and thus no further actions can be performed. I also tried adding customFooter by using customFooter as mentioned in antd Modals, but it didn't work.